# JS - executing multiple nested functions as string with parameters

Tags: javascript, string, function, eval, execute

I'm trying to execute a string in javascript without using the 'eval()' function, but I'm sticking.
Here's an example:

```
var textFunctionHolder = 'callA(15, 15, 120, 75, callB, 0, 0, 0, 0, callC, 15, 20, 240, 150, callB, 0, 0, 0, 0, callD, 30, 15, 115, 25, callZ)';
```

The string/content of the variable "textFunctionHolder" is generated via another function.
For this example, the result is directly pasted inside the var to simplify it.

Now, the variable 'textFunctionHolder' or more, the function (as String) inside the variable 'textFunctionHolder' should be executed like this:

```
callA(15, 15, 120, 75, 
   callB, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   callC, 15, 20, 240, 150, 
   callB, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   callD, 30, 15, 115, 25, 
   callZ
);
```

Is there a way to do this, without using eval()?
(The content of the variable 'textFunctionHolder' could also be much longer.)

I would be very thankful for your help.

Comment: Write your own parser and interpreter for that mini-language (or use a suitable library that does that). There's no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this.

```js
 function test(test){
        console.log(test);
    }
    
    
    var fnstring = "test('your params')";
    
    const fn =  new Function(`return ${fnstring}`);
    console.log(fn());
```

Comment: "VM933:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined"

Comment: as you can see my code works. But you need to adapt it for your case.